# how to have 2 oder by in one sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where I want to order a column from the highest value to the lowest, retrieve the highest 10 value, then after that order by random the top 10 value to display. May I know how to write a query on this situation?

Comment: Can the 10 highest value appear in the random listing as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table 
        ORDER  BY VALUE DESC 
        LIMIT  10) AS mytable 
ORDER  BY Rand()
```

Gives you a random ordering of the top 10 results